# Error with types in JTable

Tags: java, swing, types, jtable

I've got a JTable with 2 columns. The first one just contents the names of the days of the week, and the second one contents a `double` value.

There're three buttons:

- Auto-generating `double` values for testing, with this method:

  ```
  private void autoGenerate(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          for (int a=0; a<Config.n; a++){
              tabla.setValueAt(a - a*0.5, a, 1);}


  }
  ```
- To plot.
- To save the values of the table in the BD

When I try to save the data into the BD after having generated the values with the `autoGenerate`button everything works.
However when I try to save the data into the BD after having typed the values manually an **error** occurs:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
at project.Graph.jButton5ActionPerformed(Graph.java:286)
```

The button that saves the data does this:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt,Patient p) {
    try {
        for (int k = 0; k < Config.n; k++) {
            DBManager.save(p, k+1,(double)this.table.getValueAt(k, 1));
        }
   } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However when I try to save the data into the BD after having typed the values manually an error occurs:

Without any other modifications to the column classes or `CellEditor`, editing the value via the `JTable` UI will result in a `String` object being stored in the model. Thus the `ClassCastException` when retrieving the value and attempting to cast to a `double`. Consider explicitly defining the column class via the `TableModel` - this not only results in a `Double` object being stored in the model, but also affects the CellEditor as well (avoiding any errors when inputting non-numeric data).

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col){
        if ( col ==  1 ){
            return Double.class;
        }
        return String.class;
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(){
        return 2;
    }
};
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that :)